# TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined, js engine: hermes (React Native)

Tags: ios, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to build a React native mobile app, but it always presents the below error after which it has been completely built. I'm making use of TypeScript. I'm making use of Expo Cli and also I'm using react native version  "react-native": "0.71.6". If I click on dismiss, it will dismiss the error and the app will load. Kindly help! I don't know what's wrong. It's not my code because before I started writing, it was showing this, just immediately I finished setting up Eslint and Prettier [image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. The problem for me was that I exported my App using named export. When changing it into a default export everything worked like it should.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved by exporting my App as default

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35367132)